# Le meurtre comme idéal

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, oral

Dans la conversation courante, de nombreuses expressions qui connotent une violence ou une destruction sont employées dans un sens mélioratif. Par exemple, par intensité croissante :

> ça claque
>
> ça défonce
>
> ça déchire
>
> ça pète
>
> ça tue
>
> c'est une tuerie

La connotation positive de ces termes semble (à ma connaissance) être absente
en anglais, ce qui élimine *a priori* la théorie psychologique de comptoir
qui voudrait que ce soit la manifestation d'un désir de meurtre universel. 
Au contraire, il doit s'agit d'un phénomène particulier au Français.
Je voudrais savoir quelle en est l'origine ?
Même en supposant que l'intensité ait augmenté par hyperboles successives,
comment ce genre d'expression a-t-il commencé à être utilisé ?

Comment: Pas complètement absente en anglais: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=killed%20it

Comment: Pour fins de comparaison, voir aussi des emplois du verbe [_to murder_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/murder) comme dans _our team is going to murder them_ soit le gain décisif, alors qu'avec le nom ce serait négatif (_this headache is murder_). Aux É.-U., dans le contexte du jeu (vidéo en particulier), voir aussi l'emploi moderne (et déplorable à mon avis) du verbe [_to rape_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rape#Verb) comme ds. _dude, I totally raped your a** during that last game of Age of Empires_ (UrbanD) dans le sens de déclasser avec force, dominer, battre. L'association violence-gain..

Comment: To add to the previous examples: It really **blows** my mind to think humankind was able to send a probe to Pluto! I mean, quantum physics is hard, but this is just **mind-shattering**!

Comment: *La connotation positive de ces termes semble (à ma connaissance) être absente en anglais* --> To make a killing = to earn a lot of money. To kill two birds with one stone = to achieve two goals at once. Different ways to skin a cat = different ways to achieve something. I'd kill for a burger right now = I really want a burger. Etc etc etc

Comment: Est-ce que c'est une exception de l'anglais et du français ou est-ce que c'est la même chose dans toutes les langues ?

Comment: On peut dire que l’événement initial provoque un effet de surprise tel qu’il balaie brusquement tous les préjugés qu’on avait sur le sujet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comme l'ont dit les autres, la prémisse de la question ne tient pas la route. Ce phénomène est très fréquent en anglais également:

> - It killed
> - It was mind-blowing
> - It was earth-shattering
> - It was wicked
> - It was sick
> - It was terrific
> - It knocked my socks off
> - It was the shit

Je suppose en effet qu'il s'agit bien d'un universel psychologique, ou linguistique au moins. Trouvez-le sous le titre d'« [antiphrase](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiphrase) ».

Une réponse plus détaillée sur la nature de l'antiphrase apparaitrait sans doute sur [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/), où peut-être on a déjà posé la question.

---

Pour répondre à la question supplémentaire :

> Est-ce que c'est une exception de l'anglais et du français ou est-ce que c'est la même chose dans toutes les langues ?

Oui, l'antiphrase est un phénomène interlinguistique. Voici des articles en [espagnol](http://www.retoricas.com/2009/06/definicion-de-antifrasis.html) et en [allemand](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiphrasis), le dernier faisant référence lui-même à un exemple en grec. Pour un autre qui est assez fascinant (même si un peu différent), considérez qu'en hébreu biblique, on ne pouvait pas juxtaposer les mots « maudire » et « Dieu », donc lorsque Jézabel [écrit aux anciens](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Kings%2021%3A10&version=LSG) pour leur ordonner d'accuser Naboth, en hébreu elle dit « bénir » au lieu de « maudire ».

Or pour l'usage précis auquel vous vous intéressez, la violence comme louange, comme je n'en sais pas assez pour les autres langues je vous invite à poser la question sur [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/). Ce n'est pas une question qui concerne le français seul.

Comment: There's also "killer" to mean "awesome" as in "a killer move"

Comment: Oui, et tous les autres exemples sont proposés ci-dessus marchent aussi.